# friend finder api, to retrieve contacts from gmail,yahoo and hotmail using java

Tags: java, api, email, jakarta-ee, contacts

Hi I am developing an web app a java/j2ee based web app, where I have provide an feature to all the users of my web portal, to access there gmail hotmail or yahoo account and should be able to send the the content in HTML format via e-mail to his contacts or friends. I am aware there are lot of PHP api's available for this but not Java/j2ee based API's.

This is basic requirement.

Apart from using Java mail API, which has got some limitations in sending emails,is there any other mailing api's which allows to to send unlimited emails?. I have one more doubt, how do I send the HTML pages, which are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the services provide web based APIs. Although there might not be a J2EE library, you will probably get around with some common oauth, xml, http libraries.

Check this post for links to the official APIs.

[how to get contacts of gmail,yahoomail,hotmail using imap in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269089/how-to-get-contacts-of-gmail-yahoomail-hotmail-using-imap-in-php)

UPDATE:
There is a Java library you can check: http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

Answer (score 4):

*Disclosure: I'm the founder of JAIDE and SALAMBC, but I hope the information below still sounds impartial.*

You have basically two ways that you can go:

1. Scraping: Pretend you're the user by logging in to his account and then just scrape the contacts from his address book.
2. OAuth: if provided by the webmailer use this method to import the contacts - that's the official and most stable way.

### Pros and Cons:

The **problem** with those solutions is:

1. Scraping: if the site structure changes your scraper will need to be changed as well. This may happen quite often and for 25 webmailers you will have to calculate 1-2 days per month for maintaining your scraper and making sure it stays fully functional. Needs username/password.
2. OAuth: only works from the frontend as the user has to confirm popup dialogs, grant access etc. and only a small fraction of webmailers provide such an interface, e.g. Yahoo!, Hotmail and GMail. Not too many ordinary people yet know or understand OAuth.

The **advantages** are:

1. Scraping: you can use this via your backend code and, e.g. frequently (if you store his username and password, which is **not** the right thing to do, btw.), grab his contacts and do stuff.
2. OAuth: this method is quite stable, your contact importer will be resistant to any site structural changes as the magic happens via site-to-site communication (usually via REST). Doesn't need username/password.

### Contact importing libraries to the rescue!

There are a couple of open-source and commercial libraries that handle the tedious task of keeping the contact importing processes in sync with the changes made by the webmail providers.

The ones that I know of are:

**PHP**

1. OpenInviter (openinviter.com) - scraper; quite stable, updated quite quickly, open-sourced, as of now supports 61 webmailers and 43 social networks, including LinkedIn.com and XING.com.

**Java**

1. Contact List Importer 1.3.1 Java Library (code.google.com/p/contactlistimporter/) - has reached its EOL (end of life) and is not maintained anymore, was open-sourced.
2. [Improsys Contacts Importer](http://www.improsys.com/importer) - a scraper by a Bangladeshi company that provides contact importing for different programming languages (PHP, .NET, RoR etc.) and about 2 dozen webmailers. They pride themselves with having a large base of installations across different websites and seem to be around for quite some time.
3. [JAIDE-ABI](http://www.jaideabi.com) - scraper; a Java-only library from a (my) German company named JAIDE. Supports two dozen webmailers, auto-updates the importer with no downloads/restarts needed and includes support for LinkedIn and XING. The library will soon be put to use at the (new) Salam Business Club (www.salambc.com) (which is run by JAIDE), and since they're eating their own dogfood it is guaranteed that the library stays up-to-date and fully supported.

### Which one?

This might sound impartial but since OAuth  pops up windows and requests additional confirmations chances are that conversions here sink to a minimum (not empirically investigated, just a feeling!). Scrapers need your username/password and that's another obstacle to not go that way but since OAuth is not supported by all webmailers yet - and providing the username/password is requested by most social networks - the latter seems to be the more established and better choice.