# how to get contacts of gmail,yahoomail,hotmail using imap in php?

Tags: php

I want to access the contact information from gmail
Is there anyway to do this using imap php? if so please give some idea to do this.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can do that, but there are APIs available from Google/Hotmail/Yahoo which helps you get the contact information of valid users.

Please see:

**Google**

```
http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/
```

**Hotmail**

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx
```

**Yahoo**

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/
```