# Java library for authentication and importing contacts

Tags: java, jsf, facebook, openid, contacts

I need to develop following functionality for my JSF web application:

1. Authenticating users through external providers like Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, Foursquare, MySpace
2. Importing their contacts from them (Gmail, Yahoo)

I am planning to use SocialAuth Java library for the same, can some one how has used them tell me about your experience with it?

If someone know some better approach for the same, please let me know!

Comment: I just answered this in another thread, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817437/friend-finder-api-to-retrieve-contacts-from-gmail-yahoo-and-hotmail-using-java/13533487#13533487

Answer (score 3):

socialauth is your best bet! it supports almost all providers and supports a large variety of java frameworks. Even if you are not using Struts or Spring, you can use the libraries and integrate it with any framework you want.
They also have a very good documentation and examples online:

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

Also Check this previous Question :

[Taking contact list from hotmail gmail yahoo in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397933/taking-contact-list-from-hotmail-gmail-yahoo-in-java)

Comment: is openSocial and  socialGraph also similar ? How is it different from this ?